# In bfgminer, what does Accepted mean?

Tags: mining-pools, terminology, bfgminer

While mining with a pool,
I recently noticed among the numerous "Stratum from pool 0 requested" lines that
bfgminer prints,   one saying

```
 Accepted (hex number) CPU 2 Diff 288/2
```

Does this mean that I found a valid block? Or something else?

Looking at my BTC Guild account, I see no evidence of any blocks found by my computer.

Answer (score 1):

This means your pool server has accepted one block, generated your CPU, third thread, of difficulty 288 (with a minimum of two).

Comment: If this was generated by my CPU, that is odd because BTC Guild does not show any contributions from my computer.

Comment: That's odd, is your "worker name" correct in bfgminer?  In BTCGuild, in the "Your Recent PPLNS Shift Statistics" window of the Dashboard page, are any of the numbers in the "Shares" column non-zero?

Comment: Does the user need to care about the difficulty and its minimum?